# Area of the domain using line and double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral, line-integrals

I'm trying to do the area of the domain while using this formula $$A=\int \int _D\:dxdy$$ for the following: $$\left(1\right)\:D:\:x+y=1,\:y=2x+1,\:x=2y+1$$ and $$\left(2\right)\:D:\:y^2=4x+4,\:y^2=4-2x$$

For the first one I tried first isolating the y thus resulting the following:
$y=1-x$ , $y=2x+1$, $y=\frac{x-1}{2}$ so I will have the following drawing:
[image]

but I don't know how the polar coordinates should look like in this scenario, here I am stuck.

As for the second one I did the drawing and that's about it for now, I will edit when I get more ideas how to proceed.

edit for 1st one by splitting the integral:

$f1\left(x\right)=f2\left(x\right)\:<=>\:1-x=2x+1\:\rightarrow x=0$
$f1\left(x\right)=f3\left(x\right)\:<=>\:1-x=\frac{x-1}{2}\:\rightarrow x=1$
$f2\left(x\right)=f3\left(x\right)\:<=>\:2x+1=\frac{x-1}{2}\:\rightarrow x=-1$
$\rightarrow \:A=\int _{-1}^0\:f2\left(x\right)-f3\left(x\right)dx\:+\:\int _0^1\:f1\left(x\right)-f3\left(x\right)dx$

Comment: Do you *have* to use polar coordinates?

Comment: The first one is easier to set up in cartesian coordinates. You have to split your integral into two as the lines the region is bound by change.

Comment: Yes, I think so at least, I am doing it right now by splitting the integral tho because I have no idea how to do it otherwise, I will edit once I am done solving it.

Comment: I have edited it. @MathLover

Comment: Yes I see now. It is correct indeed. $f_1(x) = 1-x, f_2(x) = 2x+1, f_3(x) = \frac{x-1}{2}$

Comment: I wanted to comment but my phone died, that was a really unlucky timing.